# Cannot create a new project in Visual Studio 2019 for Tizen

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tizen

I cannot create a project for .NET Tizen using Visual Studio. I have followed the instruction carefully and get this error. There was a similar question here but the response to that question did not resolve my problem either. Does anybody have a suggestion?

The error I get:

[image: The error I get]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether VS 2019 is in your trusted list of programs?
Your user folder is a protected folder and needs specific access rights.
Type 'Controlled Folder Access' in your start menu. The third option on the tab will allow you to grant the App access to the Controlled folders